# Simply extract analytical data from Spotify API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, spotify

I'm using CRA and an Express server for a project of mine, the app shows statistics about certain artists and their tracks/albums...

I'm having difficulties figuring out how to get simple data from Spotify. Every tutorial out there expects there to be a login and authorisation to be involved; I don't need any of that, just pure statistics about the hottest tracks right now.

I do have my Spotify developers account set up and I've created a project.
Can anyone give me examples for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

For accessing any api related service you need to provide apiKey for the request you are making

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples) has examples for all three of Spotify's authorisation flows.

You want to take a look at the `Client Credentials flow`. This flow works client-side only and does not need any backend part. Using the `Client Credentials flow` you won't be able to retrieve data specific to a certain user which shouldn't be necessary in your scenario.

I assume the `project` you created is a Spotify Web API app that has a client id and a client secret. Those two values are needed in order to get the `Client Credentials flow` working.

The following snippet shows Spotify's `Client Credentials flow` example.

```js
/**
 * This is an example of a basic node.js script that performs
 * the Client Credentials oAuth2 flow to authenticate against
 * the Spotify Accounts.
 *
 * For more information, read
 * https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#client_credentials_flow
 */

var request = require('request'); // "Request" library

var client_id = 'CLIENT_ID'; // Your client id
var client_secret = 'CLIENT_SECRET'; // Your secret

// your application requests authorization
var authOptions = {
  url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
  },
  form: {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials'
  },
  json: true
};

request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

    // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
    var token = body.access_token;
    var options = {
      url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/jmperezperez',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
      },
      json: true
    };
    request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
      console.log(body);
    });
  }
});
```